# to exclude js file in IOS and include in android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am using cordova 2.1.0 for IOS/app development. I want to make only one index.html for both IOS and android. So, i wanted to include the following statement for android and exclude for IOS in index.html :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="iscroll.js"></script>
```

What is the condition i should give such that this statement runs for android and skips for IOS. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can test on the user agent

Answer (score 0):

[device.platform](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.platform) allows you to filter content based on platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function init() {
        if(device.platform =="Android"){
            $("script").attr("src", "iscroll.js").appendTo("head");
        }
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
```